# Why linq-to-sql query is translated into subquery?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Why this linq query:

```
(from c in Orders
select new 
{
   Id=c.Id, 
   DeliveryDate = c.DeliveryDate.Value
}).Take(10)
```

is translated into

```
SELECT TOP (10) [t1].[Id], [t1].[value] AS [DeliveryDate]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[DeliveryDate] AS [value]
    FROM [Orders] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
```

but when I change `DeliveryDate = c.DeliveryDate.Value` into `DeliveryDate = c.DeliveryDate` SQL query looks as simple as:

```
SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[Id], [t0].[DeliveryDate]
FROM [Orders] AS [t0]
```

Comment: Both queries would generate the same plan, so it really doesn't  matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because the `LINQ2SQL`'s translator is under-optimized. Use of a "property" (`Value`) triggers creation of a sub-query, which turns out to be unnecessary.

It is worth to note that any RDBMS worth its salt would generate identical query plans for both SQL queries, so in the end it would not matter either way.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bug / not optimized issue. I can not explain it different.